# wordpress 404.php show apache status "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date:...."

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

As said in the title: I'm running WP 3.4 and I have a 404.php.
When I call a non existing page the 404.php nicely shows up.

But at the end of the page (behind the /html tag) the apache status show up, something like

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 12:46:05 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 0 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php5

Does anyone has an idea to get rid of that and why it shows up?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a theme issue. Try putting `header("Status: 404 Not Found");` at the beginng of your theme's 404.php.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Do you have any other suggestion?